# Comparing different approaches of setting initial state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

When initializing state in React, is it bad practice to define functions inside of `useState` rather than using `useEffect`? Or is it best to use `useMemo`?

My understanding is that variables inside `useState` will be set on the first render of the component. Are there any additional considerations when using functions to set the initial state?

### Function

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Token() {
  const a = 5
  const b = 5

  const findToken = (a,b) => {
    return a*b;
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(() => {
    return findToken(a,b);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Token: {token}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### useEffect

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Token() {
  const a = 5
  const b = 5
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
   
  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(a*b);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Token: {token}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### UseMemo

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Token() { 
  const a = 5
  const b = 5

  const findToken = (a,b) => {
    return a*b;
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(useMemo(() => findToken(a,b), [a,b]));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Token: {token}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit interesting-forest-bs2hvy]

Comment: With `useState` you will get the value immediately in the first render. Your `useMemo` examply doesn't make any sense. `useEffect` will generate the values in the second render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I will try to compare some of the approaches you listed for setting initial state.

**`useState` with initializer function**

```
const [token, setToken] = useState(() => {
    return findToken(a,b);
});
```

You use this approach when `findToken` is relatively expensive, and using this approach it will *be guaranteed that `findToken` will be executed only once*. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

> If the initial state is the result of an expensive computation, you
> may provide a function instead, which will be executed only on the
> initial render

Because if you passed an *expression* instead of function to `useState`, that expression would be *run on each render*, just its value gets ignored after first render.

**Approach with `useEffect`**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(a*b);
  }, []);
```

In terms of functionality this is similar to approach with `useState` above, but this is unnecessary and causes an additional re render.

Also there is another difference, the initializer function passed to `useState` should be *[pure](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#my-initializer-or-updater-function-runs-twice)*, whereas you don't have that requirement with `useEffect`, so in the approach with `useEffect` you have advantage that you can set value in state which is result of say an API call.

**Approach with `useMemo`**

```
  const [token, setToken] = useState(useMemo(() => findToken(a,b), [a,b]));
```

Above approach doesn't make sense actually because what will happen is first time `useMemo` runs, its result will be stored in `useState`. Then, all other values `useMemo` will generate will be actually ignored - as already mentioned in the first section about passing *expressions* to `useState`.

Answer (score 2):

If the value will only be set *exactly once*, and the operation that needs to be performed isn't expensive, then it would make the most sense to avoid state and use only `useMemo`. For example, code like this:

```
const [token, setToken] = useState(() => {
    return findToken(a,b);
});
```

if `setToken` isn't called elsewhere and the calculation isn't expensive, would always be better refactored to

```
const token = useMemo(() => findToken(a, b), []);
```

If the value could be set multiple times depending on logic in your app, state will be needed.

If the operation that calculates the value is expensive enough to cause noticeable delays when rendering, then you *might* decide to compensate for that by using state, initially render an empty value, and then use `useEffect` to calculate (and set the state) for the expensive value after the component has been painted to the screen.

If you set state in an effect hook (as opposed to `useMemo`), keep in mind that that'll cause re-rendering of components lower in the tree, which is sometimes undesirable.

Comment: Deliberate - "If your code looks like this with `useState` (first code block), change to this (second code block) with `useMemo` instead"